# Passing any model class to a common method C#

Tags: c#

So, I want to create an interface which has a method that can take in any model class.
For example

I have these three property class

```
class A
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public long someID { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public long anydesign { get; set; }
}

class D
{
    public long Router { get; set; }
}
```

I have an interface

```
public interface IModel
{
    void Dosomething(A model); // Now in this example it takes the A model,But I want it to be set, so that that class that implements the interface can put any model as required
}
```

Now, I have a class that implements the mode
Since the interface only takes the A model, I can pass in the A model in the class during implementation

```
public class ImplemenationA: IModel
{
public void Dosomething(A model)
{
Console.WriteLine(model.description);
}
}
```

Say i have another implemenation Class
Now, I am guessing the below one wouldnt work, as the interface signature enforces only to take a Model A and not any other model

```
public class ImplementationB:IModel
{
   public void Dosomething(B model)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(model.someID);
    }
}
```

I want to the interface method to be invoked by any implementation class and use any model

Comment: Do the classes derive from a common class? How would you interact with them if you don't know the type, or have some common functionality?

Comment: If A,B,C,D are a model, then simply use a common interface and let your `getModel` method use that interface as a parameter (e.g. `int getModel(GenericModel model)` and `public class A : GenericModel`).

Comment: Do you mean create a generic model provider? `public interface IModelProvider<T>
{
    int getModel(T model);
}`?

Comment: You can make the interface generic, but I am not sure why you would want to do that

Comment: Looks like you've got a problem elsewhere that you need a solution for or your attempted design is wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. You can change the your signature in the interface to `int getModel(object model);` or you need to have all model classes derive from a common `BaseModel` class.

Comment: Your model classes don't seem to be related (from what you show). What would be the implementation on `getModel()` method?

Comment: Updated my code with some details but my question remains the same

Answer (score 1):

While it is unjustified what you're attempting to do... to answer the actual question it is possible using generics...

Take the following for guidance (and example)...

```
class Test : IJobTask
{

    public void Start(string val = "")
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    void MyMethod<T>(T model) where T : IJobTask;
}

public class ConcreteTest : ITest
{
    public void MyMethod<T>(T model) where T : IJobTask
    {

    }
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        var ct = new ConcreteTest();
        ct.MyMethod(new Test());
    }
}
```

Your `MyMethod` will need to perform ***checks*** and ***casts*** now which kind of defeats the purpose, but this does answer the question of "a method accepting any model"

Comment: I would also add generic parameter checking that `T` is in fact `IJobTask`. Otherwise a solution I almost started typing out myself.

Comment: @trailmax Correct, amended. PS.. coincidence that we're from the same city?

Comment: Small world indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Use interface for your property classes.

```
public interface IProperty 
{
    ...
}

class A: IProperty
{
    ...
}
class B: IProperty
{
    ...
}
class C: IProperty
{
    ...
}
class D: IProperty
{
    ...
}
```

And then you can pass interface as a parameter:

```
public interface IModel
{
    int getModel(IProperty model);
}
```